# Handling new websocket connections in express-ws

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I'm trying to create an API on a server using `express-ws` to remotely control a Raspberry-pi, starting and stopping a program on the pi to allow for safe unplugging.

The idea is that the user would click a button (start/stop) on the browser client, which would send a `GET` request to the API triggering an event to send a message over a websocket to the pi. The pi is running python using the `websockets` library to connect and receive messages from the API. The server is using the following code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const events = require('events');
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

router.get('/setDevice/:status', function(req, res){
    const status = req.params.status;
    eventEmitter.emit(status);
    res.send(status);
});

router.ws('/deviceStatus', function(ws, req){
    ws.on('open', function(){
        ws.send("Connected!");
        console.log('newConnection');
    });
    eventEmitter.on('start', function(){
        ws.send("start");
    });
    eventEmitter.on('stop', function(){
        ws.send("stop")
    });
    ws.on('close', function(){
        console.log("connection closed");
    });

});

module.exports=router;
```

I can successfully connect the pi to the server and receive the appropriate messages whenever the `GET` endpoint is hit but if I disconnect and reconnect the pi from the server it will no longer receive messages and I get the following error from the server:

```
<body>
    <h1>WebSocket is not open: readyState 3 (CLOSED)</h1>
    <h2></h2>
    <pre>Error: WebSocket is not open: readyState 3 (CLOSED)
    at WebSocket.send (C:\Projects\BLE_webapp\api\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:314:19)
    at EventEmitter.&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Projects\BLE_webapp\api\routes\socketRoutes.js:21:12)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at C:\Projects\BLE_webapp\api\routes\socketRoutes.js:11:18
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Projects\BLE_webapp\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Projects\BLE_webapp\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Projects\BLE_webapp\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Projects\BLE_webapp\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Projects\BLE_webapp\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Projects\BLE_webapp\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)</pre>
</body>
```

If I restart the server and connect the pi again everything is fine again. The error seems to suggest server is trying to hit the closed websocket and not the new one. Is there a way to tell `express` to remove the old connection on close and only focus on live one(s)?

Note: Eventually I want to expand this to support multiple pi's, with the user being able to turn on/off specific devices. I'm not sure if there are solution(s) that better allow for this. I haven't yet tested this with multiple pis but I have a feeling this will be a bigger issue with multiple.

Comment: any solutions ?